# How to execute textarea html code onclick using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is some code, it will be executed automatically at the same time fingers are lifted from keyboard.

I’d like to execute this function when click a button (onclick) not (onkeyup).

```html
<div id="result"></div>

<textarea cols="50" rows="20" 
  onkeyup="document.getElementById('result').innerHTML=this.value;">
</textarea>

<button>Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `onclick` and give the `textarea` an `ID` so you can easily access its value.

```html
<div id="result"></div>

<textarea id="text" cols="50" rows="20"></textarea>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('result').innerHTML=document.getElementById('text').value;">Submit</button>
```

Comment: make the button type=button. Some browsers will submit the page to itself when there is a button which is submit by default